# "Like me" or "such as me"?

Tags: word-usage

1. “Some people, **like me**, don’t look disabled, but the disabilities are real,” Hardiman stated. “As more of us age, disabilities will increase and many people will rely on service dogs.”
2. “Some people, **such as me**, don’t look disabled, but the disabilities are real,” Hardiman stated. “As more of us age, disabilities will increase and many people will rely on service dogs.”

Or is it something else?

Comment: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-such-as ""Like" implies comparison. "Such as" implies inclusion." So, in this case, I'd go for the latter option as "[t]he book, Hardiman’s first, also cautions against judging people whose disabilities aren’t obvious" and Hardiman seems included.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Hardiman is including "some people" with "me" (which implies using "such as"). That does seem overly formal, especially since Hardiman is refering to "me". Suggest one of the following:

"Some people, such as [insert list of people that don't look disabled],..."

"Some people, like me,..."

https://www.cliffsnotes.com/cliffsnotes/subjects/writing/what-s-the-difference-between-like-and-such-as